Outlook calendar conditional formatting based on attendees' email addresses
I am trying to create a conditional formatting rule to color all meetings that include at least one person from a particular company. I thought I could put that company's name in the 'Required Attendees -> contains' criteria, as the company name is the domain name of their email addresses. However, the meetings are not triggering the rule, I believe because the required attendees are only listed by name (Firstname Lastname format) rather than by email address. I don't want to have to list specific people's names. Is there a way to make this happen?

Outlook only keeps the display name of the attendees as a searchable property of appointments for conditional formatting rules. It doesn't support SQL filters there either. You can do this with an inbox rule to categorize invites based on "words in the recipient's address", but that has some limitations like not expanding groups

I'm afraid there is no way to achieve this in Outlook. Conditional formatting applies only to inbound messages.
